# How to change text from black to white upon hover on background black?

Tags: html, css

Currently I have one text displaying on the background image. Then on hover, there is another text which is same word which I feel that it is not right.

How to have only one same text staying in center of background image / background black - for example one show black text on background image and then on hover, white text on black background with low opacity.

See [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coxz0dbw/)

HTML

```
 <a href="/">
   <div class="text-center tkalook fishing" style="margin-bottom: 18px">
     <div class="ratio-3-1 bg-cover" style="background-image:url('http://www.gettyimages.com/CMS/Pages/ImageCollection/StaticContent/image5_170127819.jpg');">
     <span style="color: #333; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 600; position: relative; top: 62px">Fishing</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.text-center{text-align:center}
[class*="ratio"]{
  position: relative;
}

[class*="ratio"]:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
}

[class*="ratio"] .ratio-content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}


.ratio-3-1:after{padding-top: 33.3333% ;}

.bg-cover {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.tkalook {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tkalook:hover:before,
.tkalook:focus:before,
.tkalook:active:before {
    opacity: 1;
}
.tkalook:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  transition: opacity .3s;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.fishing:before{
    content: "fishing";
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.bg-cover span{
    z-index: 10;
    color: #333;
}
.fishing:hover .bg-cover span{
    color: white;
}
```

and remove the inline color for the fishing text

**jsfiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/Drea/vsnxbw0q/

Comment: nice. thanks. one more thing is if i copy same code to different pages, it will show that background image is not of same size as fiddle, cut off by more than 1/2. why is that?

Comment: if I copy the fiddle in a blank html, it perfectly works. Probably some other element or css is interfering.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.bg-cover + span {
  /* normal styles for span-text */
}
div.bg-cover:hover + span {
   /* styles for span-text when hovering div.bg-cover */
}
```

That way I think.

```
+ span
```

lets you manipulate the following ( and only that ) span-element, and if you make its style dependant on wether or not your .bg-cover element is hovered over, you should get the results that you want.

Comment: tried your example and it does not work - see fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/coxz0dbw/2/